# Three.js: Dynamically scale/rotate alpha mask-- best practices 2018?

Tags: three.js

I have a diffuse image and a greyscale alpha mask that work when combined in a material--

map: diffuse image,
alphaMap: greyscale image,
transparent: true

example here--> http://instantplaces.ca/gsap-180606-1/mask-180630-1.html

What is the best way using current three.js to dynamically rotate and/or scale the alpha mask separately from the diffuse image?

Comment: Tadaaa... you can't. Not easily anyway. You might be able to do it by cloning the model and re-adding it.. then setting some creative blending modes on the two materials.. turning off depth sorting for that branch of the tree.. and away you go!

:P

edit: You can also do it with a shader, but then you probably forgo all the built in material qualities like lighting etc. which you CAN work around, but this is a thorny problem with THREE.

If I can quell my nausea, I might try and work this into an actual answer...

Comment: An answer to this question is provided here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-dynamically-scale-rotate-alpha-mask-best-practices-2018/3298/2?u=mugen87